# Javascript. put script in div using getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom-events, video-streaming, innerhtml, video-processing

Simply put, when a user clicks a javascripted text such as "480p", I want that text to activate a Javascript function that simply places into a div the script for a video player that will then load another video of a different quality.

YouTube is a prime example. Back in the day when YouTube was young if you wanted to change quality then the player would be reset.

In my Javascript function I have `document.getElementById('videoplayer').innerHTML="<script language=\"JavaScript\">flowplayer(\"player\", \"swf location\", {clip:{data}}); </scr"+"ipt>";`

When I do this it does overwrite the div with my data, but the script will not play/activate in the div, which would reload the video player with the new stream

Any tips?

Comment: Filling a div with script after the page is loaded will not trigger the script to run.

Comment: @cale_b What do you suppose I do? I have seen "createelement", "setattribute", etc from people who say they have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use createElement instead?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doit() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.innerHTML = "flowplayer(\"player\", \"swf location\", {clip:{data}});";
  document.getElementById('videoplayer').appendChild(script);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="videoplayer">...</div>
<input type="button" value="doit" onclick="doit()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quick question.  `var script = document.createElement("script");
` where you have "script", what is that referencing? An external .js file?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already executing javascript in order to modify the DOM, why not call that function directly?

Instead of

```
document.getElementById('videoplayer').innerHTML="<script language=\"JavaScript\">flowplayer(\"player\", \"swf location\", {clip:{data}}); </scr"+"ipt>";
```

just do

```
flowplayer("player", "swf location", {clip:{data}});
```

Comment: That would normally work, but flowplayer also works by populating an anchor tag that has a specified ID and specified file location using href. So even if I did call the flowplayer function, it would refer to the static file location inside the anchor tag.

Answer (score -1):

when you need to generate AJAX answer into DIV use eval()
and dont forget that not all browsers supports createElement

Comment: Which browsers are you referring to? See: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t00

Comment: The W3C DOM Level 2 HTML defines an add method for the [select element object](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980)
but not for the options collection.However using that method is
difficult as IE implements the method with the same name with different parameters.

Comment: [see this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/createElement#compatibilitysection)